# Laravel Seed update a column from column on another table

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

I have two tables that I am using.

for example I am going to use posts.

The first is the posts table

```
id|name |author|author_id|country
1 |test |Devin |1        |South Africa
2 |test2|James |2        |Whales
3 |test3|Devin |1        |South Africa
```

Then I have the authors table

```
id|name
1 |Devin
2 |James
```

I want to add countries to the Authors table. So I made a migration to get my table to look like this

```
id|name  |country
1 |Devin |NULL
2 |James |NULL
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is to write a database seeder that will seed the countries into the authors table based on the posts table.

I want to grab the posts country for that author_id and then insert the country into the author table so that it will look like this

```
id|name  |country
1 |Devin |South Africa
2 |James |Whales
```

My question is, is it possible to do this using a seeder? Or is there a better way to do this without having to do it manually for every author.

I thought to do something like this

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class AlterOperatorsData extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $authors = App\Author::all();

        foreach ($authors as $author) {
            $country = App\Post::where('author_id', $author->id)->get()->first();
            DB::table('authors')->update([
                'country' => $country->country
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

But that looks like it would do some heavy lifting, can anyone suggest a better method, or even take a look at the current method to see if it can be improved?

Comment: @Devin Gray, Can you explain where you are populating your authors table at first place? I mean when are you putting author names there? In that very place it will be the most efficient to enter country as well.

Comment: This is a quick fix to an existing application, I am adding the foreign keys in, but for now I need to get this fix pushed. The above code works and does what it needs to, but I am looking to see if there is a better method

Comment: Even if it is an existing app :) there must be some controller or seeder which is putting author names in authors table :)

Comment: The controller does so, but the Country column is a new migration on author, so all existing authors have null as country, the goal is to have foreign keys, but it just isnt that way now, so putting out a fire before writing those

Comment: why are you not using foreign keys? post: should be : id, title, author_id, country_id, content. Also you can use faker to add that kind of data. Also why don't you use relations in model? Do something like : $author->country_id = $author->posts->first()->country_id; but i still don't like the implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in that case as OP has explained in comments, i just can suggest a small optimization in his function. You don't need to use `get()` and `first()` in same time, only `first()` will do the job:

instead of

```
$country = App\Post::where('author_id', $author->id)->get()->first();
```

use

```
$country = App\Post::where('author_id', $author->id)->first();
```

Comment: Np, wish it could be more efficient.